# The current maven profile starts the server and it keeps so that the next maven profile is not getting executed. Any solution for this?

Tags: maven, batch-file, pom.xml

This is my current maven profile which starts the server:

```
    <profile>
    <id>start-server</id>
    <build>     
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>runserver</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>                                               
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>.\server.bat</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>                       
            </executions>
      </plugin> 
    </plugins>          
    </build>
    </profile>
```

The server.bat contains the following:

> @echo off
>
> start cmd /k "cd server1_location && server1 start "
> ping 0 -w 1000 -n 10
>
> start cmd /k "cd server2_location && server2 start"

Here server2 will start only if the server1 is up and running. So,as I start the server1, I have provided ping to delay for 10 seconds for it to start up and then I'm trying to run the server2. Once this server2 has started , I need to execute my next maven profile. Since, this server2 keeps running(both servers must keep running) the next profile is not getting executed.
So, my requirement is both these servers must keep running and I also want the next maven profile to get executed.Kindly help.

Comment: The second command line should be `start "Server 1" /D "server1_location" server1 start` whereby the file name `server1` should be with file extension. The third command line should be `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 10 /NOBREAK >nul`. The fourth command line should be  `start "Server 2" /D "server2_location" server2 start` whereby the file name `server2` should be with file extension. I am not sure because of having no knowledge about *Maven*, but I think usage of `cmd /k` is not necessary at all. Open a command prompt run `start /?` and read the output help for better understanding.

Comment: @Mofi - The first solution worked. Thanks a lot!!